# Notepad++.Find something in find results

Tags: notepad++

Its a simple question.Once I perform a search in notepad++ .Is there any posibility to search something in the result of the fisrt search?

Edit.
Sometimes  i  have to do some reports about logs and i have to find some information.In most of the cases i can manage easyly by using regexp but in some cases i have to search manually.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but you could click-drag (select) the part of the code/text you want to search in

Comment: I don't believe you can do that, but why would you need to? Can't you just modify your original search criteria to include the more specific second criteria? That would have the same effect.

Comment: Could you explain why you need to do this? Why not make a more refined query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes there is**,
using **Mark** window and **Search** > **Bookmark** menu,
although it is limited to lines.

1. From menu, use **Search** > **Mark...** function.
2. In Mark dialog, check **Mark Line** and perform your search.

   - You can perform more than one search and results add together (if **Purge** is unchecked).
3. From menu, use **Search** > **Bookmark** > **Copy bookmarked lines**.

   - If you want negative selection, use **Inverse bookmarks** (from the same menu) before.
4. Open new Notepad++ document and **Paste**. Here you can search in search results.

Alternative way is to always work with the same document and use **Remove unmarked lines** or **Remove bookmarked lines** to throw away lines you do not need (then repeat searching).

Answer (score 2):

I guess this a fairly old post, but I found a method in latest version of Notepad++ that will help recursively find in "find results". If you right click inside the "Find results", you will have an option to "Find in this finder". Once you click that you get a search dialog box (similar to the one you would find in the edit area), using which you can find text inside the finder. Note that this opens another "Find result" tab. Therefore, you can recursively keep finding with "Find result" window. Another advantage is that you can use regular expressions and I have been able to do some complex nested searches using this feature. [See here for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhkzf.png)